# Dynamic link libraries and templates

Tags: c++, templates, dll

In order to support generic programming, C++ has templates. But since templates are purely a compile-time construct (much like anything else in C++), it looks like there's not much point in trying to use them in a dll.

Let's say we want to create a math library that comprises a number of templated functions. As long as this library is statically linked with an application, we're OK. You can argue
that we can statically link a `dll` to an application too (provided you have access to the source/or object files) but most of the time we just want to use the dll (by loading it via `LoadLibrary` and calling a particular function with
`GetProcAddress`)

So, does the above mean that we can't really use templates in a dll (if they're to be used externally)? And what are (if any) alternatives, apart from static libraries?

Comment: Header only libraries come to mind. Most of `boost` is header only as a matter of fact.

Comment: You can make common specializations of those templates to be imported from the dll to save size of binaries if this library is supposed to be used in many executables.

Comment: There's also the option of making the template itself a "thin" wrapper around code that is completely type unaware. Essentially, the template generates the boiler-plate on the client side, while the DLL contains the stuff that do heavy lifting.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more it doesn't make sense. The code for the templates will only be generated if there's code calling it, right?

Comment: @VTT, You' re right about the template specializations, though that's not really generic.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask this as a trick question or anything. I'm just interested in alternatives (e.g header libraries as suggested in a comment).

Comment: @dsp_user Not clear what you are asking. You can put you code in DLL, but templates must be in header file. `GetProcAddress` is hard to use with C++ code as you will have to take mangling in account. And why do you need templates if you want dynamically load DLL?

Comment: *"So, does the above mean that we can't really use templates in a dll (if they're to be used externally)?"* - Yes. *"And what are (if any) alternatives, apart from static libraries?"* - Don't use a template in the DLL interface.

Comment: @Christian Hackl Ok, I can't object to what you wrote there.

Comment: @dsp_user, really sad this question hasn't had much attention. I think a thorough answer to this would really have the chance to be a didactic reference to whoever wants to know when you should used template and when you should not, and what the criteria are.

Comment: @dsp_user, however, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16493574/5825294) is a very good answer.

Comment: @Enlico, yes, that's an interesting discussion and that particular answer by Ben is indeed very good. Unfortunately, templates in c++ are not as useful as in some other languages because they need to be recompiled for every new type that you want your template to support.  Thanks for revisiting this thread after more than 5 years.